# Is it possible to apply a photoshop color grading to an image using python?

Tags: python, image, colors

Is there a library that enables someone to apply color grading from photoshop and adjust the midtone of an image through python?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Probably. Please click [edit] and show the grading, and an image before and after you have applied it. Thank you.